# Prepared statement with user input using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am in the process of switching over from mysql to PDO and I am struggling to get my head around the select statements with user input. So I am sorry if the answer is very easy.
The connections all work as they have been tested.
I have for the following user/form input I am using:

```
$_GET['Category']
```

I have prepared the following select query:

```
if (isset($_GET['Category'])) {
$query_RS_Category = ("SELECT * FROM `meta-tags` WHERE Title = :category");
$RS_Category = $conn->prepare($query_RS_Category);
$RS_Category->bindValue(':category', '%' . str_replace('-', ' ',$_GET['Category'])  . '%');
$RS_Category->execute();
$row_RS_Category = $RS_Category->fetch();

$totalRows_RS_Category = $RS_Category->rowCount();
}
```

The tabel contains a Category_description which I would like to display with the correct Category chosen by user/form.
I tried to display it as follows:`<?php echo $row_RS_Category['Category_description']; ?>`
 however no joy.
Any help welcome

Comment: If you are using wildcards (%) you have t use `like` in your query.

Comment: "no joy". How about letting is know whether you get an error or whether the output is not what you desired. Looking at your query I think Jens is on the right track here, your query seems off.

Comment: Thanks guys, such a simple error. Can cause such a head ache. It's working now.